# Use debug-functionality without breaking architecture

Tags: development-process, debugging, encapsulation, separation-of-concerns

**note**: This is of couse about software-architecture/design-principles, but as no architecture is completely detached from its language, please note that the language i am using is C++.

I am using an API, with a debug-layer that lets you give names to API-specific objects, so that readable debug-output is generated from within the API.

Assume that i want to give the name *"ANiceObject"* to an object `A`

Because that object is relatively "low-level", it is part of an abstraction `B` in my code.
But to name it, i need access to the object itself.
I see the following options:

- provide getter inside `B` to access `A` (breaks encapsulation)
- provide interface in `B` to name `A` (`B` shouldn't have that responsibility)

Apart from this problem, i also want this debug-logic to be as separate as possible from the production-logic.

Has anyone some guidance, or ideas on how to achieve the naming of `A` for debug-purposes without breaking my architecture, and cluttering my code?

Comment: Are you naming an object or a class?

Comment: @candied_orange an object, or rather multiple objects. In reality, there will be multiple instantiations of `B`, each with a differently named object `A` inside. Note that, by naming, i refer to letting the API give a name to `A`, which is an opaque handle to me. I am not referring to giving a string-member-variable or sth. like that.
Let me know if things are unclear in my question, and i will edit to clarify.

Comment: so I take it you mean you want a reference or a pointer to this object.

Comment: @candied_orange of course i need some access to the object in order to name it. As noted i neither like the idea of providing a getter, nor the idea of letting the container-class handle the naming itself though.

Comment: Well the only other idea would be to build A yourself and pass it to B. Then you just have to remember what you named it before. The fancy name for that idea is dependency injection.

Comment: yeah, but the client shall not have to build `A`, nor even know about it.. anyway, i guess i am kind of asking for the impossible (even with a custom memory-allocator, inercepting the creation of `A` i could only give semi-helpful names without having to constantly change the memory-allocators state). I guess i will have to make some compromises, trying to keep the dev-code as separate as possible from production-code. I will post my solution as an answer, provided no satisfying answer gets posted in the meantime.

Comment: You can solve that problem by separating construction from use. Build A and B elsewhere, maybe in main.